# Flutter phone number authentication null verificationId?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to conduct a phone number login by sending sms code to my phone device using firebase auth. But the await keyword does not seem to work here. Why? my assumption is when I assign await to a function, Flutter prints the null value of the `verificationId` variable, `verificationId` gets its value within the _sendCodeToPhoneNumber function. Hence this could mean the function `_sendCodeToPhoneNumber` hasn't finished yet but the its next line of code (`print(verificationId)` in this case) is already executed. But if I am mistaken, then what is the problem? and more important, please teach me how to resolve problem? Because I have to get `verificationId`'s value and pass it to the next class.

```
String verificationId;

Future<void> _sendCodeToPhoneNumber() async {
    ...

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent = (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
      this.verificationId = verificationId; //this.verificationId here is not null because it has got a value
      print('Code sent to ${_phoneNumberController.text} with $verificationId');
    };

    ...
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
      phoneNumber: _phoneNumberController.text,
      codeSent: codeSent,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 120),
      verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
      verificationFailed: vericationFailed
    );
  }

...

FlatButton(onPressed: (){
 await _sendCodeToPhoneNumber();
 print(verificationId); // printed null despite having assigned `await` to the _sendCodeToPhoneNumber function
 ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to the following and return the `verificationId`:

```
  Future<String> _sendCodeToPhoneNumber() async {
    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent = (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
      this.verificationId = verificationId; //this.verificationId here is not null because it has got a value
      print('Code sent to ${_phoneNumberController.text} with $verificationId');
    };
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
      phoneNumber: _phoneNumberController.text,
      codeSent: codeSent,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 120),
      verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
      verificationFailed: vericationFailed
    );
    return this.verificationId;
  }
```

Also change the `onPressed`, when using `await` you need to use `async`:

```
FlatButton(onPressed: (()async{
 var result = await _sendCodeToPhoneNumber();
 print(result);
}))
```

Comment: `verificationId` is still null. This must have something to do with the scope?

Comment: wrap this with `setState(() {this.verificationId = verificationId;})`

Answer (score 0):

```
final PhoneCodeSent codeSent = (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
  this.verificationId = verificationId; //this.verificationId here is not null because it has got a value
  print('Code sent to ${_phoneNumberController.text} with $verificationId');
};
```

i think you dont need async here

Comment: i know. i already removed it in my current code and you're supposed to comment this not post this as an answer.

Comment: i cant comment cause i dont have enough reputation,im new here